# The next generation of puzzle

Tags: rebus

[image: The image shows the puzzle. I can't describe it without giving it away! Sorry.]

Who or what is or are depicted above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I'm getting

> Ensign Ro (Laren), from the row of Red Ensign flags,

The blue guys could be:

> Column-Meanies (Colm Meaney's).

Comment: Try looking up Colm Meaney :)